# VB.NET Modifying Microsoft Report Textbox Text at runtime

Tags: vb.net, textbox, runtime, report, microsoft-reporting

I want to create a Microsoft report in which should contain only one text-box and the text will be able to modify...

I have added a report WITHOUT using wizard. and have only one text-box on the report in the body section...

I wish to edit the text at run time but

```
me.reportviewer1.controls("textbox1").text= myrequiredtext
```

doesnt work...

I also tried

```
me.reportviewer1.controls("body").controls("textbox1").text = myrequiredtext
```

still doesnt work...

Comment: Are you trying to **modify** a report using report **viewer** control?

Comment: Does it not sound strange to you? :)